# Use Google Script as Java Script in Another Website's HTML page

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am new to using Google Script, but it seems like a fascinating interface with the Google Doc, Calendar, and Mail software that I look forward to using!

Our group has a website that I would love to embellish with dynamic Javascript components that access Google Docs.  What I hoped to do was create Functions in Google Script and call to them in the HTML of our website.

So, I made a Google Script page with two functions:

```
function getName(EMT_ID) {
// ...
};

function getStrikes(EMT_ID) {
// ...
};
```

These get data from a Google spreadsheet that we use.  I won't include the details because these work fine by themselves when accessed through Google Script testing environment.

I then published this as a "Web App" so that I can gain access to these functions from other platforms.

Now, on our other webpage, I added this code (exact title removed)

```
<script src="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfy[...]65K0/exec"></script>

<script>
function strikes()
{
var EMT_ID = document.getElementById('USC ID').value
document.getElementByID('output').InnerHTML = getName(EMT_ID) + ' has ' + getStrikes(EMT_ID) + '     strikes.'
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="USC ID">
<input type="button" onclick='strikes()' value='Check Strikes'>
<p>Output here:</p><p id="output"></p>
```

It was my hope that the  would allow me access to the Javascript functions from the Google Script page.  Is this the case?  If not - how else should I go about this.

Best Regards

--- EDIT

To add details - the webpage simply does not seem to respond at all to pressing the button.

Comment: Did you check the console for errors? You have an extra `)` after `.value`. That should be causing a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks - fixed that, but it's still not working out.  The console error I see is:

"getName is not defined"

Comment: When you say "exact title removed" do you mean that in production `<script src="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfy[...]65K0/exec"></script>` has a full URL, and you've just masked it in this post?

Comment: Yes - I used the URL given after publishing the Google Script.

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script functions are not directly callable from external javascript in the way that you've tried. When you published your script as a web app, you were provide a URL that the app was accessible at, via HTML. It didn't expose the functions of your script.

You do have some options, though.

1. You can create HTML within your google script using the [HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service?hl=en), and THAT html can utilize your apps-script functions indirectly via templated HTML or directly like this:

   ```
   <script>
     google.script.run.doSomething();
   </script>
   ```
2. You can use the [Content Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/content_service) to have your Apps Script provide feeds (RSS, JSON, JSONP).
3. Your published service can be written using the [UI Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp), with full access to your other apps script functions, forms, charts, etc.

There are variations on the above themes as well - this list isn't exhaustive.